# Concatenate Sequences under a Heading

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I have a file like File1. With a heading for example ">Contig1" and I want to concatenate all the sequences under the respective heading.

File1:

```
>Contig1
ACCCCATACATCCAAA
NNNNNNNNNNCATACA
AAAAAAAACTANNNNN
ACATACAAAAA
>Contig12
CCCCACAATTTTTAAA
GGGGGNNNNNCATACA
AGGAATTAACTANNAC
GGATATA
```

Expected Output:

```
>Contig1
ACCCCATACATCCAAANNNNNNNNNNCATACAAAAAAAAACTANNNNNACATACAAAAA
>Contig12
CCCCACAATTTTTAAAGGGGGNNNNNCATACAAGGAATTAACTANNACGGATATA
```

Can you please help me with it.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 perl -pe 'chomp unless /^>/; print "\n" if /^>/ and $. > 1' < File1
```

You might need to add the final newline.

Comment: Perfect it Worked perfectly. Thanks very much. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Another awk:

```
awk '{$1=RS $1 ORS}NR>1' FS='\n' RS=\> OFS= file
```

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk '/^>/{if(FNR>1)printf "\n";print;next};{printf "%s", $0}' file
```

A `perl` solution, like [@choroba's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152228/38906), but handling final newline:

```
perl -pe 'chomp unless /^>/ or eof;print "\n" if /^>/ and $. > 1' file
```